# Why is the output of this C program 0?

Tags: c

In this code I am trying to pass a pointer to the structure and then use this pointer to work on the structure members, but why is the output always showing 0?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> 
struct student
{
    int go;
} s;
void m();
void main()
{
    m(&s);  
    printf("%d",s.go);
}

void m(struct student *ptr)  
{
    ptr->go;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be? Add some more description about the problem? Only then someone here would be able to help you!

Comment: Because your compiler decided to set it to zero and you don't change it.

Comment: The ONLY two allowed signatures for `main()`, as dictated by the standard, are `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char **argv)` (or equivalently, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`); notice the *return type* of `main()`--it *cannot* be `void`.

Comment: Could you edit your questions title to - let's say a title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct student
{
   int go;
}s;
```

creates a global variable. Global variables are zero initialized unless they are initialized explicitly. That statement is equivalent to:

```
struct student
{
   int go;
};

struct student s = {0};
```

Hence the value of `s.go` is `0`. The call to `m` does not change the values of any variables. It has no effect on the output. The output will be `0` even if the call to `m(&s)` is removed.

Comment: how can initialization to zero can be avoided ?

Comment: You can avoid zero initialization by making `s` a variable in `main` instead of making it a global variable or initializing it to something else explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The global variable `s` is initialized with all members `0`.

Nothing changes the value of `s.go`, so the output is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

- When you declare your structure as **global** , their members are always initialize with its default value, if **int** than `'0'` and if **char or string** than `'\0'` . So you are getting Value `0`.

> ```
> struct student
> {
>     int go;
> } s;
> ```

Comment: They are *default-initialized* rather than *zero-initialized*, meaning "their members are always initialized with" their *default* value, rather than zero; a `char` would be set to `'\0'` and integers `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has all sorts of errors, here they are, in no particular order:

- you don't need `#include <string.h>` if you aren't using any "string" functions
- you shouldn't use global variables (if you did, it would eliminate the need to pass the pointer to `s` to functions to access the struct); you should remove the global variable (i.e., make it local) and continue to pass the pointer-to-struct as you are to `m()` in order to be able to access it outside of `main()` (where you should declare it)
- your signature for `main()` is incorrect as I pointed out in a comment to OP, and naturally you are missing the `return 0;` statement in `main()` because of this
- you are missing a newline in your `printf()`
- you aren't actually doing anything with `ptr->go` in `m()`; you aren't assigning anything to it or otherwise using it. It is printing zero because, as others have pointed out, global variables (because they are `static`,) are (default-)initialized

Here is an example with corrections (note you can initialize `s` as described by others if you wish to use it's value before you modify/set it):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct student
{
        int go;
};

void m();

int main(void)
{
        struct student s;

        m(&s);
        printf("%d\n", s.go);

        return 0;
}

void m(struct student *ptr)  
{
        ptr->go = 5;
}
```